# Gas run BTU limitation issues?

Tags: pipe, gas, natural-gas

720K BTU of simultaneous draw is being added over a distance of ~110-180ft and I have concerns about the pipe diameter being sufficient, but I don't know much about gas.

I've included a diagram showing BTU, distances, draw, and pipe diameter.  I tried looking up charts with ratings and it made me think this would not be sufficient, but the installer assured me that it would be.

Can anyone speak authoritatively to whether there would be any issues with this as planned and how those issues may manifest?  I'm thinking the house appliances may be starved as well as the pool and/or fire pit.

[image]

Comment: Make your payment to contractor contingent

Comment: I looked up the sizing chart and 1-1/4 topped out at ~450k at ~3” WC but remember you are going up to 7” WC so you should be able to handle close to 1M I would be concerned about the 1” piece from the meter it is only 2’ long but at low pressures that may throttle the flow more than the length at 1-1/4” I don’t see the actual totals so you have 2ea 200k water heaters what’s the draw on the furnaces dryer range I understand not everything will ever run at the same time but having an idea of realistic draws is needed will there be a time where both hot water heaters and furnaces will be running

Comment: @EdBeal any ideas how I can find a pipe rating table for my particular pressure - I've tried searching a bunch of things and have not had much luck. Thanks

Comment: Holy smoke, you're really betting all the marbles on future gas prices.

Comment: LOL @Harper-ReinstateUkraine - the gas company is happily upgrading the meter at no charge

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and found a page “flow calculations for high pressure natural gas”. There are many sites on line. It depends on how much math to the level of accuracy, many of the calculators are based on residential pressure but I did see some that “ of WC were used, without total BTU’s on each line and or the expected peak draw none of the calculations will be correct so with the info provided I would say it might work but depending on the how the equipment is cycled.